# Passing JSON with xmlhttpRequest request in JS

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, parameter-passing

I am echoing JSON from a php server back to the browser. I am quiet proficient with XML however am new to JSON. Can someone show me how to correctly extract the JSON from the xmlhttpRequest and then pass it into data aka an alert.

My JSON (from PHP server)

```
       {"data": {
       "message": "Open the Pod bay doors, Hal",
       "type": "request",           
       "replies" => array(
                 "id": "12321"
                 "message": "I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that!"
        )
        }
        }
```

My request in JS returns the JSON however I have no way of catching it or extracting the inside information... my ajax function is...

```
function ajax(site){  
    xmlhttp.open("GET","site",true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
       if (xmlhttp.status!=404) {
       var resp =new Function("return "+xmlhttp.responseText)();

     }
   }
 xmlhttp.send(null);
 }
```

Then I am invoking the function in window.onload

```
    window.onload = runJSON()

function runJSON(){
    var site = "http://localhost/sites/sandbox/json.php"
    ajax(site);
    ... this is what i am unsure about... how do I access the data in the object
}
alert(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"replies" => array(
             "id": "12321"
             "message": "I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that!"
    )
```

needs to be

```
"replies": {
  "id": "12321",
  "message": "I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that!"
}
```

in JavaScript, you can convert JSON to a JS object by running `JSON.parse(str)`, where you should get your `str` from a callback from inside the `onreadystatechange` handler:

```
if (xmlhttp.status!=404) {
  var resp =new Function("return "+xmlhttp.responseText)();
  ajaxDone(resp);
}
function ajaxDone(str) {
  try {
    var data = JSON.parse(str);
    console.log(data);
  } catch (x) {
    // TODO: see what happened
  }
}
```

Note: `JSON.parse` does not exist in older browsers. If you wish to support them too, you will need a library that will shim them in, like jQuery (which will incidentally also take away a lot of pain in AJAX department).

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you should parse that JSON data and return it back from ajax function.

```
var resp =new Function("return "+xmlhttp.responseText)();
```

Change this line with,

```
return JSON.parse( xmlhttp.responseText );
```

Then in runJSON function, take that json object into a variable.

```
var jd = ajax(site);
```

Then you can access all data in json.

eg. `alert( jd.data.message );` gives you "Open the Pod bay doors, Hal" as message on screen.