# ResponseText should be a json_encode, not HTML in cakephp

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp

I am trying to display the number of rows of the table. In the controller, I have a function like:

```
public function index(){
  $count= $moviecount = $this->Media->find('count');
  $this->set(array('data' => $count, '_serialize' => 'data'));
}
```

In my index.ctp, I have a regular HTML script with divs and everything. Here in my JavaScript file, I do something like this.

```
function checkTbl(){
checkBrowser();//callback function
xmlhttprequestobject.open("GET", "/url/", false); //async
xmlhttprequestobject.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(xmlhttprequestobject.readyState==4 && xmlhttprequestobject.status==200){
  alert(xmlhttprequestobject.responseText);
}
}
xmlhttprequestobject.send();
}
```

but when I click the image event onClick, the response is HTML, not the integer value of the  count. please help.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709711/passing-json-with-xmlhttprequest-request-in-js

Comment: What html comes out in your view page?

Answer (score 1):

Are you loading the RequestHandler component? If you don't call the URL with the .json extension you have to [manually set](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html#RequestHandlerComponent%3a%3arespondAs) the view to respond as json. If you parse the extensions using the router you'll automatically get a json response if the component is loaded. Did you follow the instructions on [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html)?

Comment: yes, RequestHandler is loaded. I followed the instruction on that manual. i dont have a .json extension. I dont know how or where to put it. I am not very good at cakephp. I just want the manual way. can you please help? thanks.

Comment: `I dont know how or where to put it.` in the url: `http://example.com/the/url` -> `http://example.com/the/url.json`. I.e. _ask_ for json.

Comment: If you don't request json through the extension you won't get json back automatically. I would not recommend to not use the extension. If you want to do so see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html#RequestHandlerComponent::respondAs

Answer (score 0):

If you want resposeText as json_encode then try something like this in your controller function.By using this you'll not need .ctp file.

```
 public function index()
 {
     $count= $moviecount = $this->Media->find('count');
     //$this->set(array('data' => $count, '_serialize' => 'data'));
    return new CakeResponse(array('body' => json_encode($count)));
 }
```